# Select all rows for the first N distinct child table rows

Tags: sql-server, oracle, postgresql, many-to-many

It seems like this should be a common problem with a simple solution, but I haven't found it.
I would like to compute `child_order`, which is the order of appearance of distinct child table rows as is shown below in the following data:

```
child_order   PK1  PK2       ACCESS     ACCESS_ID
1             99   Al        NULL       NULL
2             55   Charles   Accounts   1
2             55   Charles   Desktop    2
2             55   Charles   Printer    3
2             55   Charles   Servers    4
2             55   Charles   VMs        5
3             66   Charles   Desktop    2
3             66   Charles   VMs        5
4             22   Chris     Desktop    2
4             22   Chris     Printer    3
4             22   Chris     Servers    4
5             89   Evan      Desktop    2
```

Retrieved by a query like:

```
SELECT sub1.*
FROM (
    SELECT ??? as child_order, sub2.*
    FROM (
        SELECT ct.PK1, ct.PK2, pt1.ACCESS, pt1.ACCESS_ID
        FROM child_table ct
        LEFT JOIN some_linktable lt ON lt.child_id = ct.id
        LEFT JOIN parent_table1 pt1 ON lt.parent_id = pt1.id
        WHERE ct.PK2 IN ('Charles', 'Evan', 'Al', 'Chris')
        ORDER BY ct.PK2, pt1.ACCESS -- Order must be preserved
    ) sub2
) sub1
WHERE child_order < 10 AND (other_conditions)
```

I can use subqueries, aggregates, analytics, etc. but not really CTEs/"WITH" statements or temporary tables because of the complexity of generating SQL for them dynamically.

Specifically, I am generating pagination SQL (for several DBMSs) for search results from a query joining several tables.
I am trying to figure out how to simply show the top N rows, not counting repeats due to a join (e.g. Chris counts as only one row. `Access` shows "Desktop, Printer, Servers").

I've tried `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PK1, PK2)`, but of course I get ranking in PK1 PK2 order, which is useless for the WHERE clause. Al, for example, would get a value higher than 1.

I've tried `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PK2, ACCESS)`, but it enumerates only the search terms, not the child table rows.

I've tried `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PK2, ACCESS ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` (to get DENSE_RANK to use the row order it is given, which is how I want to rank values) but only "1" is returned.

I'll omit my other "*try random stuff*"-phase attempts.

I would like to avoid having a `SELECT DISTINCT PK1, PK2 WHERE (search) ORDER BY (sortorder)` subquery because there may be zero or very many primary key fields so dynamic SQL generation would be tricky and, additionally, I suspect the performance would suck with all the `WHERE sub3.field1 = sub2.field1 AND sub3.field2 = sub2.field2...` checks.

Answer (score 1):

Despite your misgivings about `SELECT DISTINCT`, this might be the best choice for a sub-query:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY PK2) AS child_order, PK1, PK2
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT PK1, PK2
  FROM child_table
  WHERE PK2 IN ('Charles', 'Evan', 'Al', 'Chris')
  ORDER BY PK2
  LIMIT 9) sub2
```

The `child_order` field depends only on table `child_table` and you want only 9 rows of them, so compute the `child_order` in a sub-query on that table only. After you have that you can join to the other tables. If you have an index on `child_table(PK1, PK2)` this should be a very fast index-only search. It takes some of the filtering and the limiting inside, so the enveloping query is much simpler:

```
SELECT sub1.child_order, PK1, PK2, pt1.ACCESS, pt1.ACCESS_ID
FROM child_table ct
JOIN (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY PK2) AS child_order, PK1, PK2
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PK1, PK2
    FROM child_table
    WHERE PK2 IN ('Charles', 'Evan', 'Al', 'Chris')
    ORDER BY PK2
    LIMIT 9) sub2
  ) sub1 USING (PK1, PK2)
LEFT JOIN some_linktable lt ON lt.child_id = ct.id
LEFT JOIN parent_table1 pt1 ON lt.parent_id = pt1.id
WHERE <other conditions>
ORDER BY sub1.child_order, pt1.ACCESS; -- Faster to order by int
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this won't fulfill the requirements because correct order isn't kept.
The inner query sorts only by the child table, but without the sort against the parent table, the appropriate "first N rows" are lost.
One could as a subquery execute the entire filtered, joined, sorted main query, then execute it again joining against itself for row order, but that seems incredibly complicated for what I thought would be a very common SQL problem: Search, sort, and pagination of results from a join. Does this seem unreasonable?